# Python: reading from rfile in SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

Tags: python-2.7, simplehttpserver

While overloading SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, my function blocks on self.rfile.read(). How do I find out if there is any data in rfile before reading? Alternatively, is there a non-blocking read call that returns in absence of data?

Comment: I looked at socket.py and noticed a comment that says "We never leave read() with any leftover data from a new recv() call in our internal buffer." (socket.py:338 in python2.7 libs). In this case where can I check for  any additional data in an http command sent by the client? (corner case while testing)

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Comment: I haven't yet. Since this was a personal project, it got sidetracked. Will definitely update when I solve this.

Answer (score 0):

For the record the solution is to only try to read as many bytes as specified in the header Content-Length. ie something like:

```
contentLength = int(request.headers['Content-Length'])
payload = str(request.rfile.read(contentLength))
```

Comment: Will not work for streaming mode, where there is no `Content-Length`

Answer (score -1):

I just solved a case like this.

I'm pretty sure what's "gottcha" on this is an infinite stream of bits being written to your socket by the client your connected to.  This is often called "pre-connect" and it happens because http/tcp/HttpServer doesn't make a significant distinction between "chunks" and single bytes being fed slowly to the connection.  If you see the response header contains `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` you are a candidate for this happening.  Google Chrome works this way and is a good test. If fire fox and IE work, but Chrome doesn't when you recieve a reponse from the same website, then this what's probably happening.

Possible solution:

1. In CPython 3.7 the HttpServer has options that support pre-connect.  Look at the HttpThreadingServer in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html).
2. Put the request handing in a separate thread, and timeout that thread when the read operation takes too long.

   Both of these are potentially painful solutions, but at least it should get you started.